# Need help understanding this TODO provider

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I just downloaded an `Ionic` project from internet.

On the file: `src/pages/home/home.ts` I have the following fragment of code:

```
...
addTodo() {
    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Add Todo',
        message: 'Describe your todo below:',
        inputs: [
            {
                name: 'title'
            }
        ],
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Cancel'
            },
            {
                text: 'Save',
                handler: todo => {
                    if (todo) {
                        this.showLoader();
                        this.todoService.createTodo(todo).then(
                            result => {
                                this.loading.dismiss();
                                this.todos = result;
                                console.log("todo created");
                            },
                            err => {
                                this.loading.dismiss();
                                console.log("not allowed");
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    prompt.present();
}
...
```

On the file: `src/providers/todos.ts` I have the following fragment of code:

```
...
createTodo(todo) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', this.authService.token);
        this.http
            .post(
                'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/todos',
                JSON.stringify(todo),
                { headers: headers }
            )
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    resolve(res);
                },
                err => {
                    reject(err);
                }
            );
    });
}
...
```

**My question is:**

On the file: `home.ts` where we have: `handler: todo => { ... }` what's the content of the parameter: `todo`?, is it an object?, is it a string with the title of the todo?

What happens inside...

```
this.todoService.createTodo(todo)
```

Comment: please check todo in console.log... and update your question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@davidesp your first question was **what's the content of the parameter: todo?**

`todo` is a object which was depend on `inputs` fields, `todo` is user defined name you can give any name of this object and no need to define like `subscribe` has two state one success block another error block.Here inputs have one field `title` so its only one item in object.

```
        inputs: [
            {
                name: 'title'
            }
        ]
```

Please check this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/)

When you click on `Save` button then following code happens (describe with comments)

```
addTodo() {
    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Add Todo',
        message: 'Describe your todo below:',
        inputs: [
            {
                name: 'title'
            }
        ],
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Cancel'
            },
            {
                text: 'Save',
                handler: todo => {
                    if (todo) { //check data avaiable
                        this.showLoader(); //call loader
                        this.todoService.createTodo(todo)//call todoService
                           .then(
                            result => { //success block todoService
                                this.loading.dismiss(); //loader dismiss call
                                this.todos = result;
                                console.log("todo created");
                            },
                            err => { //error block todoService
                                this.loading.dismiss(); //loader dismiss call
                                console.log("not allowed");
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    prompt.present();
}
```

@davidesp your second question was **What happens inside `this.todoService.createTodo(todo)`**

```
createTodo(todo) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers(); // server request Headers initilization
        // setting header value ...
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', this.authService.token);
        // Calling http post method here first parameter is url second data and third is header value ...
        this.http
            .post(
                'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/todos',
                JSON.stringify(todo),
                { headers: headers }
            )
            //map converting response json value 
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                res => { //success block 
                    resolve(res); // resolve promise 
                },
                err => { //error block 
                    reject(err);// reject promise 
                }
            );
    });
}
```

Comment: but how is the `todo` object created?, I don't find any Schema for the `todo` object on the client side (not backend)

Answer (score 0):

When you press 'Save' button in the form, the handler function would work.

So, the purpose of save button is create new todo items on Database or Backend system.

I added comments in your codes :

```
buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Cancel'
            },
            {
                text: 'Save',
                handler: todo => {
                    if (todo) {
                        this.showLoader(); // <= show loading spinning image maybe
                        this.todoService.createTodo(todo).then( // <= call createTodo of todoService and wait for the server's response.

                        result => {
                            this.loading.dismiss(); // <= loading spinning image close
                            this.todos = result; // <= save server's response ( it would be new todo item info or server's success message. it depends on the api servers defined responses. )
                            console.log("todo created");
                        },
                        err => {
                            this.loading.dismiss();
                            console.log("not allowed");
                        }
                    );
```

...

And insite the createTodo function is

```
createTodo(todo) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers(); // <= set header to call post request to the api server.
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', this.authService.token);
        this.http
            .post(
                'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/todos',
                JSON.stringify(todo),
                { headers: headers }
            )
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(   // <= when server success to create new todo item, server will send success response or error messages.
                res => {
                    resolve(res); // <= success case
                },
                err => {
                    reject(err); // <= error case
                }
            );
    });
}
```

I hope this would be helpful to you :)

Comment: but how is the `todo` object created?, I don't find any Schema for the `todo` object on the client side (not backend)